# Do storage encryption systems care about size of data?

Tags: encryption, birthday-attack, secure-storage

I was studying about Psuedorandom functions and their use as encryption functions. One of the things that I read was "birthday bound" or ["birthday attack"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).

When encryption is used for something like disk encryption, the amount of data being encrypted can be very large and over time be large enough to launch a birthday attack. Do storage encryption systems care about it? Or is it not big of a deal? Or is my assumption of data size being a problem, wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's common for encryption algorithm specs to specify a hard limit of how much data you should encrypt with the same key.  For example, consider the AES-XTS encryption algorithm, which was designed specifically for full-disk encryption:

- The [IEEE specification](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1619/email/pdf00086.pdf) recommends that the length of a "data unit" (e.g., disk sector or block) encrypted with a single key should not exceed $2^{20}$ AES blocks.
- The [NIST recommendation](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38e/final) upgrades this to a hard requirement.

Since each AES block is 16 bytes, and $2^{20}$ bytes is 1 MiB, that's a limit of 16 MiB ($2^{24}$ bytes) per data unit.  You need $2^{44}$ such data units to hit the $2^{64}$-block birthday bound, but 1 TiB ($2^{40}$ bytes) is only $2^{40} \div 2^{24} = 2^{16}$ times the size of the 16 GiB maximum data unit.  So disks don't appear to be big enough yet to hit this limit.

But note that this limit is *per encryption key*.  If you use multiple encryption keys then you get to reset the limit for each key that you use.  It's already common to use individual keys for each disk volume, and some filesystems (e.g, Apple's APFS) already support per-file encryption keys.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to know is actually in the [birthday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) link you provided.  Look at the large *"Desired probability of random collision"* table in the middle of the page.

Assume the simplest of disc encryption with 128 bit AES, no advanced key tweaking or master/slave keys.  The disc itself will generate unrecoverable errors every [~10^15 bits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0701166.pdf).  You'll need to make allowance for improvements with time since this paper was published.    That's ~10^13 128 bit AES writes. From the table, to achieve a similar probability of collision, you'd generate ~10^12 hashes, which is ~10^13 bytes, or 10,000TB.  Western Digital's [best](https://www.wdc.com/products/internal-storage/wd-gold-enterprise-class-hard-drive.html) is currently 12TB, so you'll never generate enough cipher for it to be a problem. Yet. SAS discs are much smaller.

Note. I've kinda done some serious rounding (AES = 100 bits) to help with the numbers. You get the idea though.

Answer (score 2):

Storage encryption systems typically use a tweakable block cipher (or a block cipher in a tweakable mode of operation such as XTS). A tweakable block cipher is essentially a block cipher with an extra input (the tweak) in addition to the key which allows each encrypted block to act like it had a different key. The tweak changes frequently and thus prevents a birthday attack. Liskov, Rivest, & Wagner's [paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/tweak-joc.pdf) introduced the idea and is a pretty good description.

Thomas Ptacek's article "[You don't want XTS](https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/04/30/you-dont-want-xts/)" is also worth reading, as XTS is very commonly used in software for storage encryption.